# Linked list advantage over list

Tags: c#, arraylist, data-structures, linked-list

I read in many articles where it mentioned that linked list will perform well when we have to perform insert/delete in middle of the collection. But i have a doubt here. I am learning data structure please let me know if my understanding is not correct.

Suppose if we have 10 items in a list

index:-   0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9

items:-   A | I | Z | S | J | T | V | J | A | T

And i want to delete item at index 6 that means "V" then further items  we have to shift one level up. I understand that this shifting is a costly operation when we have very big list.

In case of Linked list we dont have to shift items as we can just change prev and next pointer to the new node.

Example-

HeadNode A=> D=> Z=> S=> C=> W=> M=> Q=> E=> T

Now suppose we have to delete W then as per my understanding we have to traverse till W from headnode (A). So then this is also costly operation like in list where we are shifting items after deleting.
Then how this scenario can be advantage of linked list over list

Comment: This is a very well documented data structure, and there are boat loads of information about it on the internet that will explain it 1000 different ways

Comment: To Delete an Item (from any collection) you first have to "Find" it. That operation is always going to be same/similar. Its the Cost that you cannot change. What you are saving on is Shift/Compaction after the Deletion. In you Array situation - You are assuming that you know the INDEX from where item has to be removed. Rather look at Delete V from Array/List. Now you have to find it first.

Comment: I think if somebody is downvoting, they should tell the reason also so that we will  not repeat same mistake again. As for this question I am not sure why I got downvote. I am not saying this is good question as I already said I am learning DS. But atleast if i am aware where I did mistake, I will not repeat same mistake again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insertion and deletion in the middle of a linked list is only fast when you already have a reference to the node being inserted or removed, and you therefore do *not* have to traverse the list to find it.

In C#, that makes the `LinkedList` collection useful when objects are identified by reference (so you don't have to find them), or through another collection or index, and each item in the list can have a reference to its `LinkedListNode`.

A good example of `LinkedList` use would be an LRU cache -- the cache consists of a dictionary and a linked list.  When you find an item in the dictionary, you move to the front of the list.  If the item has a reference to its `LinkedListNode` then you can move it to the front in constant time, no matter where in the list was originally.

In Java, which doesn't expose the node class, the `LinkedList` collection is mostly useless.

Comment: "In Java, which doesn't expose the node class, the LinkedList collection is mostly useless" : True. Just wanted to add 2 more points though. 1) Add/remove at head in LinkedList in O(1) while its O(n) in ArrayList, and 2) If ListIterator is used, add/remove in middle in both LinkedList and ArrayList are O(1)

Answer (score 0):

Advantage of the linked list is that elements can be added to it indefinitely(depends on memory available), while an array will eventually get filled or have to be resized (a costly operation that isn't always possible).

Linked Lists are best suited when the total number of items in the list are not known and random access to elements in not required. Arrays are more suited when we have an idea about the upper limit to the number of items in the list and random access to elements is required.

Also if you don't already know the index of the item you want to delete in the array. You will need to find that element and then perform the shift. In linked list you just need to find the element and remove the pointers, there is no need for shifting elements.